# CSS3 transparent gradient similar with Photoshop ColorPicker

Tags: css, gradient

I try to create a transparent gradient with CSS. I need it for a color picker app. I have a transparent PNG I could use but its is 20kb large and would request a new HTTP request. The code should be ultralight.

Here is what I've done so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/78SEK/
The one above its the good one and the bottom one is made with CSS.

I had also tryd something with HTML5 Canvas but I could not get the exact match.
Is there a way I could do this?
Thanx

Comment: Why does it need to be transparent?  I could see why the png might need to be, if you use it as an overlay... but does the css need to be?

Comment: yes, if you change to page body color you will seethe same thing Photoshop is using for its Color Picker. I pretty much try to copy the PNG including the opacity.

Comment: Ah, I think I see... You have several overlapping gradients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need 2 gradients.  One going from white to transparent left to right, and one going from transparent to black top to bottom:

http://jsfiddle.net/SKFRS/

HTML:

```
<div id="white_grad"><div id="black_grad"></div></div>
<p>CSS3 Gradient</p>
```

CSS:

```
#white_grad {
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height:255px;
    width:255px;
}

#black_grad {
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border:1px solid #333333;
    height:255px;
    width:255px;
}
```

You could also make the bottom gradient go from black to your desired color, not transparent.  Then your background could be any color, and your div would still have the desired effect:

http://jsfiddle.net/SKFRS/3/

If you want to programatically change it, the first method is probably better, with a bottom solid background layer.

Comment: Thanx, its perfect. You just saved me 20Kb :)